# Converting to "int" failed for parameter "num"

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I have this code that should just send a picture with some numbers but it doesn't work

```
class crafting(commands.Cog):
  "info about user"
  def __init__(self, bot:commands.bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def crafting(ctx, name: str, num: int):
    if name == "gbs":
      img = Image.open("gearboxcrafting.png")
      font = ImageFont.truetype("ARIAL.TTF", 30)
      numfont = ImageFont.truetype("Bold-X3RG.ttf", 40)
      
      copper_rod = num * 10
      steel_bolt = num * 50
      steel_plate = num * 25
      
      draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
  
      draw.text((368,565), str(copper_rod), (37, 35, 32), font=font)
      draw.text((368,656), str(steel_bolt), (37, 35, 32), font=font)
      draw.text((368,747), str(steel_plate), (37, 35, 32), font=font)
      draw.text((109,926), str(num), (37, 35, 32), font=numfont)
  
      img.save("text.png")
      
      await ctx.send(file = discord.File("text.png"))
```

but if I use it, it shows me this error

```
Ignoring exception in command crafting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 467, in _actual_conversion
    return converter(argument)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gbs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "/home/runner/lmcbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 476, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "num".
```

I tried everything I know to convert int to num but it didn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the command is in a class (a cog) it should take `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Please add the function execution line and the arguments you are passing to it.

Comment: You are getting a ValueError. Converting to "int" failed for parameter "num". You should investigate this parameter; make sure the correct "value" is being fed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Łukasz Kwieciński mentioned, the 'crafting' method needs to take 'self' as first argument, as it's a member of a class.

Cheers